# Flavor Oscillations, the case of leptons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, neutrinos, leptons

In the neutrino sector neutral particle oscillation occurs which gives rise to neutrino oscillation. From my currrent understanding , the observation of the neutrino oscillation occurred because the coherence length of this phenomenon is sufficiently large that the state does not become de-coherent in the length scales of the phenomena studied. E.g. the state is still coherent when it arrives on earth after being produced in the sun.

> I was wondering why I never heard about flavor oscillation in the lepton sector, e.g. $e^{-}$ ⇄ $\mu^{-}$ ⇄ $\tau^{-}$.

Is this because the coherence length (which should be inversely proportional to the mass of the considered particle) is so short that the phenomenon is completely negligible?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76804/mixing-of-quarks-neutrinos-and-leptons

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277432/why-dont-other-massive-particles-change-of-flavor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; try the [neutrino oscillation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation#Propagation_and_interference) for the idealized system of  ultrarelativistic charged leptons, say e and μ.

In natural units,  *L ≈ π E / Δm²*; so,  for a μ with mass of 0.1 GeV and an e of relatively negligible mass, zipping at an E of hundreds of GeVs,
we are talking about fermis for L, the oscillation length.

Can't think of a realistic lepton flavor oscillation experiment not involving quadrillions of oscillations vitiating coherence...